# Meaning of to "will someone on"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

In the following [extract](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/live-david-cameron-gives-heartfelt-8410180)  from David Cameron's last speech as PM, I don't understand the last part which includes "will someone on":

> *And the PM won applause and a standing ovation from Tories - but not Labour - as he said: "I will miss the roar of the crowd. I will miss the barbs of the opposition. But I will be **willing you on."***

I could not find a definition of "will someone on" in online dictionaries.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though one answer analyses this as an example of the single-word verb 'will', and this probably explains the development of the construction, [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_phrasal_verbs_with_particle_(on)) considers 'will on' a transitive multi-word verb (it uses the term 'phrasal verb').

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/will_on) has a definition for the term:

> **will on**  Verb
>
> [Categories: English lemmas ... English verbs ... English phrasal verbs ... English phrasal verbs with particle (on)]
>
> to will on
>
> To wish intensely that someone succeeds in what they are doing. Often
>   implies a silent, or almost inaudible wish.

[reformatted]

There is often debate over whether some of these expressions should be considered as unitary [multi-word verbs] or not.

Comment: I'm about 50 - 50 with Silenus's interpretation on this particular unitary-or-not judgement call. I'm just adding the alternative view.

Comment: - I think  your finding is very interesting, and actually the usage is very close to that of a phrasal verb.

Comment: If you'd like to read more about the 'unitary-or-not' debate, [Richard Weit](http://www.sl.ac.th/html_edu/cgi-bin/sl/main_php/print_informed.php?id_count_inform=819) gives a[n over-?] simple introduction, and [The Verb-Particle Combination in English by Bruce Fraser](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/412527.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) goes deeper;  [Phrasal Verbs (Telling Particles from Prepositions) _ The Historical Rise of the English Phrasal Verb by George J. M. Lamont](http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~cpercy/courses/6361lamont.html) lists constituency tests

Comment: Do take care hereabouts; the term 'phrasal verb', for instance, is used in at least three conflicting and thus potentially confusing ways.

Answer (score 18):

In this context, ***[to will](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/will)*** means something like

> [*WITH OBJECT AND INFINITIVE*]
>
> Make or try to make (someone) do something or (something) happen by the exercise of mental powers:
>
> *'reluctantly he willed himself to turn and go back'*
>
> *'she stared into the fog, willing it to clear'*

Your example doesn't include the infinitive, but rather the small clause construction "you on", which can be read as something like "you to go on".

Thus, Cameron is saying something like:

> But I will be intending/wishing/urging you to go on.

Answer (score 3):

*But I will be willing you on.*

This means "I will be wishing for you to progress/advance."

"Willing something/someone on" is like when your team has the ball and is advancing and you try to "wish" them forward to a goal.  Sometimes it implies physically cheering them onward, sometimes the "cheering" is unspoken and the most an observer of you might see is teeth gritting and a stiffening of the posture.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. You mean it is an expression you can hear in sports? I never heard it before. Btw, Who is "you"?

Comment: @Saturana Google "willing them on to win" (and include the quotes in your search so you get the *exact* phrase) and you will see plenty of examples about sports.

Answer (score 3):

To *will* something is *to [try to] cause or change by an act of will or volition*. [Merriam-Webster (third usage)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will)

> **will** - *transitive verb* - decree, ordain

This is something you can do, whether or not you have to authority or power to follow through: I can *will* my bowling ball to turn back toward the center of the lane, even as it tips into the gutter.

It indicates what you *hope* to happen, so Mr. Cameron will be hoping the Tories do well and continue on. Whether he exercises any force other than the force of his own desire and verbal support is yet to be known.